# UDP send of 1237 bytes failed with error 35

Tags: node.js, electron, peerjs

I have an Electron and PeerJS built app. It uses PeerJS to make file transfer between 2 WebRTC data channel connected clients. File transfer works perfectly, but sender side main process (not browser renderer process) gets following random console.log errors observed in VS code Terminal console:

```
[29071:0703/195348.080594:ERROR:stun_port.cc(308)] Port[dc1b4600:0:1:0:local:Net[en0:192.168.8.x/24:Wifi:id=1]]: UDP send of 1237 bytes failed with error 35
[29071:0703/195348.081743:ERROR:stun_port.cc(308)] Port[dc1b4600:0:1:0:local:Net[en0:192.168.8.x/24:Wifi:id=1]]: UDP send of 1237 bytes failed with error 35
```

The data channel packet size is 512KB (file is sliced into chunks). Above error shows for every few chunks.

Main process uses followings to slice file into chunks:

```
const chunkSize = 512 * 1024;  
fs.createReadStream(fullFileName, {highWaterMark: chunkSize});
```

It's originated from NodeJS file read or PeerJS? Since it's from VS code, it should not be from WebRTC. But it shows "stun_port.cc" which should be WebRTC related issue.

What's the reason of the error? How to fix it?

Comment: You aren't showing any code that actually uses UDP so it's a bit hard for us to have any idea what's going on here.  `fs.createReadStream()` uses local file I/O, so no networking involved in that.  I would guess this is related to whatever you're doing with PeerJS.

Comment: Since the error shows in VS code debugger Terminal console, which is ipcMain process, I thought it has nothing to do with app's browser ipcRenderer process. Why stun_port.cc error shows up in ipcMain process? The code of WebRTC is pretty large, and can transfer file perfectly. I could not think of which part of PeerJS code has problem.

Comment: Well, why don't you run your app from the regular command prompt outside of VS code and see if the error is still there.  That would at least rule out VS code as the source.